# Webview not play audio, microphone when power save and turn off screen

Tags: android, webview, power-saving

My app using WebRTC to phone call, so I used webview to load sipjs connect to server make phone call sucessful.

But it have a bug: Making phone call in power save and turn off screen, webview not play audio from server and not have audio from microphone send to server. Not turn off sreen, it ok.

I think in power save and turn off screen, webview is limited network or something render. I don't know exactly.

How to resolve that bug.

Comment: I think that you can't resolve this *bug* as it isn't a bug actually. It is expected behaviour (limiting things in power save mode)

Comment: Thanks for you time. So, you have any solution to prevent webview limited

Comment: I think that there should be no solution, as it has to be limited. Since the user wants to save his battery, you should have no way to override his actions.